# What are the definitions for valid and invalid pp-tokens?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, c89

I want to extensively use the ##-operator and enum magic to handle a huge bunch of similar access-operations, error handling and data flow.

If applying the `##` and `#` preprocessor operators results in an invalid pp-token, the behavior is undefined in C.

The order of preprocessor operation in general is not defined (*) in C90 (see [The token pasting operator](http://www.complete-concrete-concise.com/programming/c/preprocessor-the-token-pasting-operator)). Now in some cases it happens (said so in different sources, including the MISRA Committee, and the referenced page) that the order of multiple ##/#-Operators influences the occurrence of undefined behavior. But I have a really hard time to understand the examples of these sources and pin down the common rule.

So my questions are:

1. What are the rules for valid pp-tokens?
2. Are there difference between the different C and C++ Standards?
3. My current problem: Is the following legal with all 2 operator orders?(**)

   ```
   #define test(A) test_## A ## _THING
   int test(0001) = 2;
   ```

Comments:

(*) I don't use "is undefined" because this has nothing to do with undefined behavior yet IMHO, but rather unspecified behavior. More than one ## or # operator being applied do not in general render the program to be erroneous. There is obviously an order — we just can't predict which — so the order is unspecified.

(**) This is no actual application for the numbering. But the pattern is equivalent.

Comment: Here is a good reference for the C preprocessor: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### What are the rules for valid *pp-tokens*?

These are spelled out in the respective standards; C11 §6.4 and C++11 §2.4. In both cases, they correspond to the production *preprocessing-token*. Aside from *pp-number*, they shouldn't be too surprising. The remaining possibilities are identifiers (including keywords), "punctuators" (in C++, *preprocessing-op-or-punc*), string and character literals, and any single non-whitespace character which doesn't match any other production.

With a few exceptions, any sequence of characters can be decomposed into a sequence of valid *preprocessing-tokens*. (One exception is unmatched quotes and apostrophes: a single quote or apostrophe is not a valid *preprocessing-token*, so a text including an unterminated string or character literal cannot be tokenised.)

In the context of the `##` operator, though, the result of the concatenation must be a single *preprocessing-token*. So an invalid concatenation is a concatenation whose result is a sequence of characters which comprise multiple *preprocessing-tokens*.

### Are there differences between C and C++?

Yes, there are slight differences:

- C++ has user defined string and character literals, and allows "raw" string literals. These literals will be tokenized differently in C, so they might be multiple *preprocessing-tokens* or (in the case of raw string literals) even invalid *preprocessing-tokens*.
- C++ includes the symbols `::`, `.*` and `->*`, all of which would be tokenised as two *punctuator* tokens in C. Also, in C++, some things which look like keywords (eg. `new`, `delete`) are part of *preprocessing-op-or-punc* (although these symbols are valid *preprocessing-tokens* in both languages.)
- C allows hexadecimal floating point literals (eg. `1.1p-3`), which are not valid *preprocessing-tokens* in C++.
- C++ allows apostrophes to be used in integer literals as separators (`1'000'000'000`). In C, this would probably result in unmatched apostrophes.
- There are minor differences in the handling of universal character names (eg. `\u0234`).
- In C++, `<::` will be tokenised as `<`, `::` unless it is followed by `:` or `>`. (`<:::` and `<::>` are tokenised normally, using the longest-match rule.) In C, there are no exceptions to the longest-match rule; `<::` is always tokenised using the longest-match rule, so the first token will always be `<:`.

### Is it legal to concatenate `test_`, `0001`, and `_THING`, even though concatenation order is unspecified?

Yes, that is legal in both languages.

```
    test_ ## 0001 => test_0001             (identifier)
    test_0001 ## _THING => test_0001_THING (identifier)

    0001 ## _THING => 0001_THING           (pp-number)
    test_ ## 0001_THING => test_0001_THING (identifier)
```

### What are examples of invalid token concatenation?

Suppose we have

```
#define concat3(a, b, c) a ## b ## c
```

Now, the following are invalid regardless of concatenation order:

```
concat3(., ., .)
```

`..` is not a token even though `...` is. But the concatenation must proceed in some order, and `..` would be a necessary intermediate value; since that is not a single token, the concatenation would be invalid.

```
concat3(27,e,-7)
```

Here, `-7` is two tokens, so it cannot be concatenated.

And here is a case in which concatenation order matters:

```
concat3(27e, -, 7)
```

If this is concatenated left-to-right, it will result in `27e- ## 7`, which is the concatenation of two pp-numbers. But `-` cannot be concatenated with `7`, because (as above) `-7` is not a single token.

### What exactly is a *pp-number*?

In general terms, a *pp-number* is a superset of tokens which might be converted into (single) numeric literals or might be invalid. The definition is intentionally broad, partly in order to allow (some) token concatenations, and partly to insulate the preprocessor from the periodic changes in numeric formats. The precise definition can be found in the respective standards, but informally a token is a *pp-number* if:

- It starts with a decimal digit or a period (`.`) followed by a decimal digit.
- The rest of the token is letters, numbers and periods, possibly including sign characters (`+`, `-`) if preceded by an exponent symbol. The exponent symbol can be `E` or `e` in both languages; and also `P` and `p` in C since C99.
- In C++, a *pp-number* can also include (but not start with) an apostrophe followed by a letter or digit.
- Note: Above, `letter` includes underscore. Also, universal character names can be used (except following an apostrophe in C++).

Once preprocessing is terminated, all *pp-numbers* will be converted to numeric literals if possible. If the conversion is not possible (because the token doesn't correspond to the syntax for any numeric literal), the program is invalid.

Comment: Do you know if there are also difference between different iterations of the C standard and between the different iterations of the C++ standard?

Comment: @MarkA.: Yes, there are differences. All of the incompatibilities I mention are the result of features added in one or the other language at some point in time (and not necessarily the same time in both languages, in the case where they exist in both languages.) This includes unicode characters, raw strings, hexadecimal floats, apostrophe separators, alternate tokens ("digraphs"), etc. The set of string encoding- prefixes (currently `u`, `u8`, `U` and `L`) has changed over time. But the broad outline is the same.

Comment: @MarkA. The digraphs such as `<:` were not in C89/90 but were added in C99.

Comment: @MarkA.: If your question has to do with concatenation order, though, the answer is no. In all versions of the C and C++ standards, the order of application of the concatenation operator is unspecified, and valid programs cannot rely on it.

Comment: What problems does the concept of having pp-number include the character sequences "E+", "E-", "e+", and "e-", solve that couldn't be solved just as well by saying that a pp-number that ends with "e" or "E" must be followed by a string of digits, or else a "+" or "-" and a string of digits?  Sure that would accept "1.23E + 7" as a valid floating-point constant, but in what sense would that be a bigger problem than mandating a space between hex constant that's congruent to 14 mod 16, and a following + or - character?

Comment: @supercat Re: character sequences "E+", "E-", "e+", and "e-": from Rationale for C: "The notion of preprocessing numbers was introduced to simplify the description of
preprocessing." (6.4.8 Preprocessing numbers). Btw, MSVC does not diagnose `0xe+1`.

Comment: @pmor: The Rationale claims that, but I fail to see *how* requiring that compilers look for a two-character sequence within a PP-number would be simpler than saying that a PP-number will be terminated by the first character outside the set `[0-9A-Za-z\.]`?  If the compiler downstream of the preprocessor would concatenate numeric pieces like it concatenates strings, the preprocessor woudln't need to care about e-format or p-format floating point numbers at all.  How does the design which was supposedly chosen to "simplify" the preprocfessor in any way make it simpler than it would be otherwise?

Comment: @pmor: Indeed, prior to the introduction of hex floating-point literals, I see no reason the preprocessor should need to care about any kind of token other than strings of `[0-9A-Za-z_]`.  Some implementations given something like `#define join(x,y) x##y` followed by `a = b join(+,++) c;` might process it as `a=b++ +c;` and others as `a=b+ ++c;` but so what?  If the Standard treated both interpretations as valid, that would make clear that programmers should avoid such constructs if they care about how they're interpreted.  There's no need for the Standard forbid such cases.

Comment: I think the most common situation where invlaid PP-tokens would be formed would be those where the text of the right operand of the ## pasting operator has been formed into a token whose text would be split between two or more tokens if the text of the operands were concatenated and rescanned.  For example, if one were to paste `a-` and `->b`, the right operand starts with a token `->`, but concatenating and rescanning would yield `a -- > b`, no token of which contains `->`.

Comment: @supercat "The C89 Committee felt that it was better to tolerate such anomalies than burden the preprocessor with a more exact, and exacting, lexical specification." Personally I'd probably "burden the preprocessor with a more exact, and exacting, lexical specification". As for `join(+,++)`: "If the result is not a valid preprocessing token, the behavior is undefined." Clang produces: `error: pasting formed '+++', an invalid preprocessing token`.

Comment: @pmor: I've read the Rationale, but I fail to see how allowing the preprocessor to be agnostic to the boundaries of any tokens other than strings of the form `[0-9][0-9A-a-z_\.]*` or `[A-Za-z_][0-9A-Za-z_]*` would be more of a "burden" than the rules the Standard adopted, except for a compiler that happened to already have implemented token-processing logic like what the Standard would end up mandating.

Comment: @pmor: I suspect what actually happened is that the authors of the Standard expected that implementations would generally continue processing things as they always had, effectively processing a dialect that extended the semantics of the language to handle constructs beyond those mandated, but they failed to realize that some corner cases involving the stringize operator make it necessary for the preprocessor to worry about token boundaries that the preprocessor was not intended to have to care about.

Comment: @pmor: If the preprocessor were to treat every character outside `[0-9A-Za-z_#]` as a discrete token, but regard certain pairs of tokens as operators within a `#if` operator, and it suppressed macro expansion between encountering a token that starts with a digit and encountering a token that was neither a period nor sequence of `[0-9A-Za-z_]`, how would that not be easier than the implementing the behavior mandated by the Standard, and in what cases would it not be just as useful?

Comment: @supercat As rici mentioned "the definition is intentionally broad, partly in order to allow (some) token concatenations, and partly to insulate the preprocessor from the periodic changes in numeric formats". Do you think that anomalies like `0xe+1` worth these (two) features?

Comment: @pmor: If the rules were changed so that ## would be agnostic as to whether a token could be formed by taking at least one character from both sides, macro expansion would be disabled for alphanumeric tokens that occur between a leading-digit alphanumeric token and the next token that isn't alphanumeric or period, and if it treated each individual non-alphanumeric character as a discrete preprocessor token, what useful (non-contrived) constructs would that fail to handle as mandated by the Standard?

Comment: @pmor: Prior to the introduction of hex floating-point literals, there would be no need for a rule to suppress macro expansion of alphanumeric sequences following a leading-zero alphanumeric token, but without that rule, `0x12.cap+2` could get mangled if there were a macro definition for `cap`.  The rule, though, is pretty simple to both describe and process, and would accommodate any numeric format that starts with a zero and in which any character outside the range `[0-9A-Za-z_\.]` is followed by a digit.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define test(A) test_## A ## _THING
int test(0001) = 2;
```

This is legal with both LTR and RTL evaluation, since both `test_0001` and `0001_THING` are valid preprocessor-tokens. The former is an identifier, while the latter is a pp-number; pp-numbers are not checked for suffix correctness until a later stage of compilation; think e.g. `0001u` an unsigned octal literal.

A few examples to show that the order of evaluation *does* matter:

```
#define paste2(a,b) a##b
#define paste(a,b) paste2(a,b)
#if defined(LTR)
#define paste3(a,b,c) paste(paste(a,b),c)
#elif defined(RTL)
#define paste3(a,b,c) paste(a,paste(b,c))
#else
#define paste3(a,b,c)  a##b##c
#endif
double a = paste3(1,.,e3), b = paste3(1e,+,3);  // OK LTR, invalid RTL

#define stringify2(x) #x
#define stringify(x) stringify2(x)
#define stringify_paste3(a,b,c) stringify(paste3(a,b,c))
char s[] = stringify_paste3(%:,%,:);            // invalid LTR, OK RTL
```

If your compiler uses a consistent order of evaluation (either LTR or RTL) *and* presents an error on generation of an invalid pp-token, then precisely one of these lines will generate an error. Naturally, a lax compiler could well allow both, while a strict compiler might allow neither.

The second example is rather contrived; because of the way the grammar is constructed it's very difficult to find a pp-token that is valid when build RTL but not when built LTR.

There are no significant differences between C and C++ in this regard; the two standards have identical language (up to section headers) describing the process of macro replacement. The only way the language could influence the process would be in the valid preprocessing-tokens: C++ (especially recently) has more forms of valid preprocessing-tokens, such as user-defined string literals.

Comment: 10.e is a valid pp-number; i don't see why your rtl example requires rtl evaluation.